# How to print a pdf file using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

Here is my code where I try to print a pdf file in my default printer.
I get no errors but the file still is not getting printed as expected.

```
            //print to printer
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.Verb = "print";
                info.FileName = filePath;
                info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();

                p.WaitForInputIdle();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                    p.Kill();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think here you need to start process CMD.exe first and run the print as command (as a argument to the process). Below code might help...

```c#
 string filePath = @"Name_Of_File";
 string printerNameOrPRN = @"""Printer_PRN""";
 //print to printer
 try
 {
  string strCmdText;
  strCmdText = "/C print /D:" + printerNameOrPRN + " " + filePath;
  ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
  info.FileName = "CMD.exe";
  info.Arguments = strCmdText;
  info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  Process p = new Process();
  p.StartInfo = info;
  p.Start();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
  if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
    p.Kill();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```